# How to migrate tables on a running site for laravel?

Tags: laravel, migrate

Using laravel how to migrate table(if there are changes) on a running site?

We use CMD if working offline. My question is simple if I have a site running fine already (online) then how to migrate...we can't run CMD there, right?

Answer (score 3):

one way is using `Artisan` command in `routes` like this:

```
Route::get('/migrate', function(){
    \Artisan::call('migrate');
    dd('migrated!');
});
```

and then call this route.

**remember to REMOVE this route after MIGRATING...!**

Answer (score 1):

if your server is linux you can use ssh to access command environment.

If your personal system is Windows you can install **putty** to open ssh.

how it works is in this link :

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404604/using-ssh-in-putty-(windows)

how to access ssh in mac system is in this link

https://www.servermania.com/kb/articles/ssh-mac/

after access ssh you most first install composer then locate your project folder and now you can call all **php artisan** command like

```
 php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

import Artisan at web.php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

you can write migrate route like this

```
Route::get('migrate',function(){
   Artisan::call('migrate');
```

});

you can write migrate:rollback route like this

```
Route::get('rollback',function(){
   Artisan::call('migrate:rollback');
});
```

you can write routes & view clearing route like this

```
Route::get('vr-clear',function(){
   Artisan::call('route:clear');
   Artisan::call('view:clear');
});
```

Basically i will suggest you too use like this reboot route for clearing cache and route clear after deploying the Laravel project to live.
Because sometimes it can be show some error message.

```
Route::get('reboot',function(){
  Artisan::call('view:clear');
  Artisan::call('route:clear');
  Artisan::call('config:clear');
  Artisan::call('cache:clear');
  Artisan::call('key:generate');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is also simple. You're still going to use CLI or CMD while your site is online. If you use cPanel, go to Advanced tab and select terminal. Inside your terminal use cd to change drive. Default drive might probably be public_html. cd public_html, cd <your_project_folder>php artisan migrate.

This will process migration while your application is running.